# Using math within a reply Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have a discord bot running on an old server in my basement. for some reason, I can't get the correct output from a reply.

full code:

```
    module.exports = {
    name: 'ping',
    description: 'Pings Bot, then replies with latency -- for debuging',
    execute(message, args) {
        message.channel.send('Latency is ${Date.now() - message.createdTimestamp}ms. API Latency is ${Math.round(client.ws.ping)}ms');
    },
};
```

where:

```
message.channel.send(' Pong! Latency is ${Date.now() - message.createdTimestamp}ms. API Latency is ${Math.round(client.ws.ping)}ms');
```

comes out exactly as its written:

```
Latency is ${Date.now() - message.createdTimestamp}ms. API Latency is ${Math.round(client.ws.ping)}ms
```

the bot doesn't crash so I can't pull any error messages, I'm not sure where the problem lies and I'm still relatively new to this

Thanks in advance! if there's anything else that would be helpful to know, just ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `${}` within a string, you cannot use single-quotes ('), instead you need slanted quotes (`). Otherwise it just treats it as part of the string.

```
execute(message, args) {
    message.channel.send(`Latency is ${Date.now() - message.createdTimestamp}ms. API Latency is ${Math.round(client.ws.ping)}ms`);
},
```